# Call a function within the .done of a Jquery.post call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am confused on this one.

I am trying to call another defined function within the AJAX done and i get the function cannot be found error.

I have also tried to declare this as a variable and use that still get the same issue, cannot find the function.

```
var self = this
...
$.post.done(function(respose) {
    self.init_customer_dropdown();
})
```

If i call the function outside of the AJAX request works fine

Here is the full code block

```
$('.save-client-modal').on('click', function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
//Save Cutomer to Database

var url = admin_url + "clients/create_client_ajax";

var data = {};
...

$.post(url, data).done(function (response){
    response = JSON.parse(response);

    if(response.success == true || response.success == "true")
    {
         init_customer_dropdown(); <-- will not run this function
    }
    else
    {
        alert_float('warning', response.message);
    }
});

});

function init_customer_dropdown()
{
    alert("Customer Dropdown");
}
```

Thanks in Advance
Mike

Comment: Hello, is any code running inside `.done()`? I mean, before `response` parse. If so, this means that if statement is failing - may be any parsing issues.

Comment: Also, try to move your `init_customer_dropdown()` outside jQuery's scope.

Comment: Json. parse removes undefined properties.,just log the hell out of your code on every stem och the syack, the exact problem will become apparent